# Iterator on Map gets converted to Object in Java

Tags: haxe

Map's keys method `keys ():Iterator<K>` gets converted to `public java.lang.Object keys()` in Java. Is there a way to generate an actual Iterator type?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not without changing the generator code, because `Iterator<T>` is an anonymous structure type, which is represented by `Object` at run-time. Looking at the actual implementation, it's also implemented as an anonymous object, so `Object` is the best one can have at run-time. However, it could be reworked to some concrete class which would be returned by StringMap/IntMap/ObjectMap iterator method made inline.